# Regex pipe needs to take first match

Tags: regex

My regular expression is like this:

```
      .*(kgrj4e|\*)[^:]*:([^;]*);?
```

The 'kgrj4e' part is a userid and is dynamic. The PR.... parts are printers. If the userid is not found I want the default printer (PR12346).

For first test string below I want result to be PR12345, but I get PR12346

snljoe,snlaks,kgrj4e,snlbla:PR12345;*:PR12346

Note: the users snljoe, snlaks and snlbla are just examples and can be totally different. In fact the list of users can be longer or smaller.

For second test string below I want result to be PR12346

snljoe,snlaks,snlbla:PR12345;*:PR12346

How to fix the regular expression so both test strings give the expected result?

Comment: do you want to extract the string `PR12346`?

Comment: do you need two separate regex for two different cases?

Comment: Why `PR12345` in the first example? `kgrj4e` is not right before the value you need, there is a `snlbla`

Comment: I now have two different regexes, but want to combine them into one. The 'kgrj4e' part is a userid and is dynamic. The PR.... are printers. I want the default printer PR12346 to be selected when the userid is not found.

Comment: If a user ID is dynamic, how can we match it? Is it always 3rd and inbetween `snlaks` and `snlbla`? And what is the regex flavor?

Comment: What is the regex flavor? See [`\bsnlaks,(?|[^,]+,snlbla:(\w+)|snlbla:.*\*:(\w+))`](https://regex101.com/r/yZ9dS5/3)

Comment: No, its not always third in. It can be anywhere, it is a comma-separated list of users, the list can also contain only one user.

Comment: There must be some restriction. Please see my answer with an example how to detect the users list.

Comment: The userids like 'snlaks' are not fixed values.

Comment: So, you want to find the first printer if some user is not present in the string? Then use [`^(?:(?!.*,kgrj4e(?:[;,])).*\*:(\w+)|.*?(PR\d+).*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7jD9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number with a search and replace:

Search for: `^(?:(?!.*,kgrj4e(?:[;,])).*\*:(\w+)|.*?(PR\d+).*)`

Replace with: `$1$2`

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7jD9/1)

I assume that the `kgrj4e` is a user-defined value that should be missing in the string to match the last printer value. If it is present, the first printer value is returned.

Comment: Have you checked this approach? Again, what is the language you are using?